# Finding if two values exist for the same ID in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

i have a data table result set that has two columns that i need to focus on ActionCode and ProcessID

I'm trying to find the fastest way to see if there is both AcitonCodes A and E, both for the same ProcessID.

i'm finding all these examples of how to search a data table for a value, but can't figure out how to constrain it to the same ID. please help.

this right now works, in a way that it returns all A and E rows, but i can't seem to find a way to return a result only if A and E both belong to the same ProcessID.

```
DataRow[] foundAuthors = dt.Select("ActionCode = '" + 'A' + "' or ActionCode = '" + 'E' + "'" );
```

and

```
var x = from e in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                where e.Field<int>("ActionCode") == 'A' &&
                                      e.Field<int>("SeriesID") == seriesid
                                select e;
```

and a final question. is LINQ the optimal way to go about this? is there a "newer" and more preferred namespace i should be using?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without an IDE I came up the following bit of LINQ, may require tweaking:

```
    dt[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(r => new { pID = (long)r["ProcessID"], action = (string)r["ActionCode"] })
    .Where(x => x.action == "A" || x.action == "E")
    .GroupBy(x => x.pID, x => x.action)
    .Where(g => new []{"A","E"}.Intersect(g).Count() == 2)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you're looking for ([Here is full DotNetFiddle Example of the below](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W0mAg8)):

```
    string[] myList = new string[]{"A", "E"};

    var results = authors.Where(x => myList.Contains(x.ActionCode))
                        .GroupBy(x => x.ProcessId, x => x.ActionCode)
                        .Where(d => myList.All(dv => d.Contains(dv)))
                        .Select(x => new { ProcessId = x.Key, ActionCode = x.ToList()} ).ToList();
```